# How can I define the buildozer.spec requirements when converting Python Kivy to APK?

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, buildozer

I would like to convert my python kivy project into an APK file through Google Colab. In this process I have to define the requirements in the buildozer.spec manually, namely I have to give the dependencies. Here is my imported modules in my main.py file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.garden.moretransitions import PixelTransition,RippleTransition,BlurTransition,RVBTransition
from kivy.uix.image import Image, AsyncImage
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
import random
import time
```

Can somebody help me to define the buildozer.spec requirements?

I have tried many ways to define my dependencies, but my APK isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

In your spec file, in the requirements you should have something like this:

```
requirements=kivy,kivymd,python,android
```

Now kivy garden is installed as a normal package as stated [here](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/pull/1142), so these should be all requirements that you need in your spec file. If your app crashes at startup there can be also other problems maybe not related to the dependencies. You can try to see what's going on on your device when launching your app using `buildozer android logcat` with your device connected to your computer. However, this can be done with buildozer installed on a linux machine. If you use windows and you have the linux subsystem, you can try to install buildozer and run it from there (but I use Ubuntu, so I am not sure how it works on windows).

Answer (score 0):

kivy.garden.moretransitions isn't supported in Android, so you can't use in buildozer.